# Drag and drop destination not working after deleting/recreating a widget

Tags: c++, drag-and-drop, gtk3

I have implemented drag-and-drop of a Gtk3 widget in a Linux environment. It works, but to my surprise I discovered that if I delete and recreate the widget (or just make a copy of the widget), the background window is no longer a valid destination target for the new widget (the dragged icon just moves back to its moved-from position).

It is still possible to move the new widget if the destination target is the widget itself ...

Any idea what is going on?

I enclose the whole C++ code and build commands.

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gtk-3.0:/usr/include/glib-2.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include:/usr/include/pango-1.0:/usr/include/harfbuzz:/usr/include/cairo:/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0:/usr/include/atk-1.0:/usr/include/graphene-1.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/graphene-1.0/include;export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu;export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

g++ -Wall -o test test.cpp class.cpp -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lcairo
```

**class.h**

```cpp
 #include <string>
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>

 class Counter
 {

    public:

        struct State
        {
            int x;
            int y;
            std::string name;           
        };      
    
        Counter(const char *name, int x, int y);
    
        ~Counter();         
    
        State state;
    
        static GtkWidget* fixedLayout;

        static GtkTargetEntry source_targets[];

        static GtkTargetEntry dest_targets[];   
    
        static gboolean drag_drop ( GtkWidget* self,
                                    GdkDragContext* context,
                                    gint x,
                                    gint y,
                                    guint time,
                                    gpointer user_data
                                  );
        static float alpha;
    
    private:

    
        std::string name;       // string id of this counter 
            
        GtkWidget *counter;
    
        GdkPixbuf *baseBuffer;
    
        GtkWidget *image;
    
        int width;      
        int height; 
    
        GtkWidget *makePiece();
    
 };
```

**class.cpp**

```cpp
#include "class.h"

using namespace std;

GtkWidget* Counter::fixedLayout = NULL;

float Counter::alpha = 0.5;


Counter::Counter(const char *name, int x, int y)
{
    this->name = string(name);
    this->state.x = x;
    this->state.y = y;  
    this->state.name = string(name);
    
    this->baseBuffer = gdk_pixbuf_new (GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, false, 8, 72, 72);
    gdk_pixbuf_fill ( this->baseBuffer, 0xff000000 );

    this->image = gtk_image_new_from_pixbuf (this->baseBuffer);

    this->width = gdk_pixbuf_get_width(this->baseBuffer);
    this->height = gdk_pixbuf_get_height(this->baseBuffer);

    this->counter = makePiece();

    gtk_fixed_put ( GTK_FIXED(fixedLayout), this->counter, 
        this->state.x, this->state.y );

    gtk_widget_show_all(fixedLayout);

}


Counter::~Counter() 
{
    gtk_widget_destroy(this->counter);
    g_object_unref(this->baseBuffer);
}


int offset_x;
int offset_y;

Counter *dragged = NULL;

GtkTargetEntry Counter::source_targets[] = {
         { (gchar *)GTK_TYPE_WIDGET, GTK_TARGET_SAME_APP, 0 }
};


GtkTargetEntry Counter::dest_targets[] = {          
        { (gchar *)GTK_TYPE_WINDOW, GTK_TARGET_SAME_APP, 0 },
        { (gchar *)GTK_TYPE_WIDGET, GTK_TARGET_SAME_APP, 1 }
};


static void drag_begin (GtkWidget* self,
                        GdkDragContext* context,
                        gpointer user_data
                       )
{

    dragged = (Counter *)user_data;

    GdkDevice *device = gdk_drag_context_get_device (context);
    GdkWindow *window = gtk_widget_get_parent_window (self);

    gint abs_x, abs_y;

    (void)gdk_window_get_device_position ( window, device, &abs_x, &abs_y, NULL );

    gint start_x, start_y;
    gtk_widget_translate_coordinates(self, gtk_widget_get_toplevel(self), 0, 0, 
        &start_x, &start_y);


    offset_x = abs_x - start_x;
    offset_y = abs_y - start_y;

    gint width = gtk_widget_get_allocated_width (self);
    gint height = gtk_widget_get_allocated_height (self);
 
    cairo_surface_t *surface = cairo_image_surface_create (CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,
                                                           width, height);                                    
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create (surface); 
       
    gtk_widget_draw (self, cr);                             

    gtk_drag_set_icon_surface (context, surface);
    gdk_drag_context_set_hotspot ( context, offset_x, offset_y);


    // opacity

    GdkWindow *dragicon = gdk_drag_context_get_drag_window (context);
    gdk_window_set_opacity ( dragicon, Counter::alpha );

    cairo_destroy (cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy (surface);

}


static void drag_get ( GtkWidget* self,
                       GdkDragContext* context,
                       GtkSelectionData* data,
                       guint info,
                       guint time,
                       gpointer user_data
                     )
{   
    gtk_selection_data_set ( data,
                             gdk_atom_intern_static_string ("GTK_WIDGET"),
                             32,
                             (const guchar *)self,
                             sizeof (gpointer)
                           );                          
}


gboolean Counter::drag_drop ( GtkWidget* self,
                              GdkDragContext* context,
                              gint x,
                              gint y,
                              guint time,
                              gpointer user_data
                            )
{
        
    int dx = x - offset_x;
    int dy = y - offset_y;

    // hack, x and y are now relative to the 426 window
        dy -= 26;
    
    // find where we drag from
    gint wx, wy;    
    gtk_widget_translate_coordinates(self, gtk_widget_get_toplevel(dragged->counter), 
        0, 0, &wx, &wy);
        

    GtkWidget *container = gtk_widget_get_parent (dragged->counter); 

    if (GTK_IS_EVENT_BOX(self))
    {
        gtk_fixed_move ( GTK_FIXED(container), dragged->counter, wx + dx, wy + dy );
        dragged->state.x = wx + dx;
        dragged->state.y = wy + dy;
    }
    
            
    if (GTK_IS_WINDOW(self))
    {
        gtk_fixed_move ( GTK_FIXED(container), dragged->counter, dx, dy );  
        dragged->state.x = dx;
        dragged->state.y = dy;  
    }

    gtk_drag_finish (context, TRUE, TRUE, time);    
        
    return TRUE;

}


static void do_activate ( GtkMenuItem* self,
                          gpointer user_data
                        )
{
    delete( (Counter *)user_data );
}


static gboolean do_popup ( GtkWidget *self,
                           GdkEventButton *event,
                           gpointer user_data
                         )
{
    if (event->button == 3)
    {
    
        GtkWidget *menu = gtk_menu_new ();       
        GtkWidget *menuitem = gtk_menu_item_new_with_label ("Delete");
    
        g_signal_connect (menuitem, 
                          "activate", 
                          G_CALLBACK (do_activate), 
                          user_data);
  
        gtk_menu_shell_append (GTK_MENU_SHELL (menu), menuitem);
        gtk_widget_show_all(menu);      
        gtk_menu_popup_at_pointer ( GTK_MENU(menu), (GdkEvent *)event );
    
        return TRUE;
    
    }

    return FALSE;
    
}


GtkWidget* Counter::makePiece()
{
    GtkWidget *event_box = gtk_event_box_new(); 
    g_signal_connect (event_box, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK (do_popup), 
        (gpointer)this);

    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (event_box), GTK_WIDGET(this->image));
    gtk_event_box_set_above_child( GTK_EVENT_BOX(event_box), TRUE );

    // add signals for drag-and-drop

    gtk_drag_source_set ( event_box, GDK_BUTTON1_MASK, Counter::source_targets, 1, 
        GDK_ACTION_MOVE );
    gtk_drag_dest_set   ( event_box, GTK_DEST_DEFAULT_ALL, Counter::dest_targets, 2, 
        GDK_ACTION_MOVE);

    g_signal_connect (event_box, "drag-begin", G_CALLBACK (drag_begin), (gpointer)this);        
    g_signal_connect (event_box, "drag-data-get", G_CALLBACK (drag_get), NULL);

    g_signal_connect (event_box, "drag-drop", G_CALLBACK (drag_drop), NULL);

    return event_box;

}
```

**test.cpp**

```cpp
#include "class.h"
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

using namespace std;


gboolean on_draw (GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer data)
{
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    return FALSE;
}


static void createdCallback (GSimpleAction *action, GVariant *var, gpointer pt)
{
    (void)new Counter("foo", 100, 130);
}


static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
    // set up main window

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new (app);

    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
    gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 600, 426);

    gtk_window_set_position ( GTK_WINDOW (window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER );

    Counter::fixedLayout = gtk_fixed_new ();    
    gtk_container_add ( GTK_CONTAINER(window), Counter::fixedLayout );
    g_signal_connect(Counter::fixedLayout, "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw), NULL);
    gtk_application_add_window (app, GTK_WINDOW(window));


    // set up drag-drop signals to main window

    gtk_drag_dest_set ( window, GTK_DEST_DEFAULT_ALL, Counter::dest_targets, 2, 
        GDK_ACTION_MOVE);

    g_signal_connect (window, "drag-drop", G_CALLBACK (Counter::drag_drop), NULL);

    // menu bar
    GMenu *menubar = g_menu_new();
    GMenu *submenu = g_menu_new ();

    GSimpleAction *create_action = g_simple_action_new ( "create", NULL);
    g_signal_connect( create_action, "activate", G_CALLBACK ( createdCallback ),  
        window );

    GActionMap *action_map = G_ACTION_MAP ( app );
    g_action_map_add_action ( action_map, G_ACTION ( create_action ) );

    g_menu_append (submenu, "Create" , "app.create" );

    GMenuItem *filemenu = g_menu_item_new ("_File", NULL);
    g_menu_item_set_submenu (filemenu, G_MENU_MODEL (submenu));
    g_menu_append_item (menubar, filemenu);

    const gchar *const accreload[] = { "<Ctrl>c", NULL };
    gtk_application_set_accels_for_action(GTK_APPLICATION(app), "app.create", 
        accreload);

    gtk_application_set_menubar (app, (GMenuModel *)menubar);
    gtk_application_window_set_show_menubar(GTK_APPLICATION_WINDOW(window), TRUE);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));

    g_object_unref ( submenu );
    g_object_unref ( menubar ); 


    (void)new Counter("foo", 100, 130);


    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}



int main() 
{  
    static GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", 
        G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    (void)g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), 0, NULL);

    g_object_unref (app);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work to serve my purposes. I made `window` global in test.cpp.

**test.cpp**

```
...

GtkWidget *window;


static void activate (GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{

   // set up main window


   window = gtk_application_window_new (app);

...
```

I repeated the call to `gtk_drag_dest_set` in class.cpp.

**class.cpp**

```
...

extern GtkWidget *window;

...

GtkWidget* Counter::makePiece()
{

    ...

    //repeat    
    gtk_drag_dest_set (window, GTK_DEST_DEFAULT_ALL, Counter::dest_targets, 2, GDK_ACTION_MOVE);


    return event_box;

}
```

But this is no real solution. If I delete the initial counter and create a new one, then the new counter has drag destination WINDOW as expected. But if just drag the initial counter to another position and create a new counter, then the initial counter has lost its WINDOW drag destination!

Is this some kind of conflict with statics or memory overwrite problems?